# LESS checkstyle for jenkins

Tags: css, jenkins, continuous-integration, less, checkstyle

I would like to know if there is a checkstyle for less. I know of CSSLint but i don't know about Less and if it is available for jenkins.

Anyone knows more about this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Twitter have a code quality tool called [RECESS](http://twitter.github.io/recess/).  It is built on top of LESS and can compile LESS files to CSS and then lint them.  It has quite a few useful options and certainly worth having a look at.

[Twitter RECESS](https://github.com/twitter/recess)